# Split a String based on a specific pattern of characters

Tags: sql, sql-server

Basically, I would like to be able to Split a long text field after each date into unique rows that correspond to the dates. The source field "Notes" is just a long running text field with multiple comments over time with a distinct date ... initially, I tried splitting off the '-' after the date which works to some degree, except where there are dashes elsewhere in the text. So I'm thinking of something where I could split off of each unique instance of a date (mm/dd/yy) ... one issue is the length is not consistent meaning, it could be:

**'m/d/yy-' or 'mm/dd/yy-' or 'mm/d/yy-'**

Example Data > 'Notes' Column:

> 3/30/16-Had a meeting 2/5/16-LVM 10/5/15-Spoke to customer

*A single cell could have multiple dates and comments in it
Looking for end result like this:

```
Date        Value
3/30/16     Had a meeting
2/15/16     LVM
10/5/15     Spoke to customer
```

I am using something basic like the below, but wondering if I can get a little more sophisticated with the STRING_SPLIT

> ```
> SELECT NOTES, VALUE
> FROM SRC_TABLE
> CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(NOTES,  '-')
> ```

Appreciate any insights or ideas!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  And explain what the issue is with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  I think this does what you want:

```
select t.*, s.*
from src_table t outer apply 
     (select value as value_date
      from string_split(t.notes, '-') s
      where s.value like '%/%/%' and s.value not like '%/%/%/%'
     ) s;
```

EDIT:

If you just want to split on the first `-`, you can use:

```
select left(notes, charindex('-', notes + '-') - 1),
       stuff(notes, 1, charindex('-', notes + '-'), '')
from src_table;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d56e879b51c3cb8390ae25eaf982d2f1) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, that definitely seems a bit closer than I was ... I updated my original post to show the "hopeful" result ... sorry a bit new here, so trying to figure out all the formatting  ... to clarify ... those 3 values would all be in one cell ... so im trying to split out multiple dates into their own rows.

Comment: I did thank you ... so the issue is that the source data has multiple date/notes combinations in one cell ... so I'm looking to do two separate actions:  1) Split the initial cell into multiple rows for every occurrence of a date and then 2) separate the date from the notes .... the Left() function will solve the second, and I think your first portion of code is on the right track for the first part, it's just a little off on splitting at the right points.